# Antlr Grammar file and newline

Tags: antlr

I am having trouble writing the grammar for antlr, I tried doing some code but not sure if its right or

1. Strings may be surrounded in either matching quotes or matching double quotes. (This one is done already).
2. Numbers may be integers or floating point numbers.  Numbers should not have a leading '0', unless it is the first digit to the left of the '.'.  Floating point numbers must have at lease one number to the right of the '.'.
3. Whitespace outside of a string has no meaning.  (This one is done for you).
4. Newlines may be either Windows (\r\n) or Unix (\n) newlines.

It should have the following parsing rules:

1. A file is made of zero or more lines.  (This one is done for you).
2. A line is made of 0 or more cells, separated by commas.  Every line ends with a newline.
3. A cell is either a string or a number.

```
grammar CSV;

// Literals
STRING  : '"' ~["\n\r]*? '"' | '\'' ~['\n\r]*? '\'' ;
NUMBER  : ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')* EXPONENT?
        |   '.' ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT?
        |   ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT
        ;

// Whitespace
WS      : [ \t]+ -> skip ; // ignore whitespace
NL      :  '\n'
        | '\r\n'
        ;

file: line* ;

line: // ***YOUR CODE HERE***
    ;
```

I am not sure if NUMBER or NL are right or not.

Comment: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/csv You can learn from example.

Comment: `NUMBER` and `NL` look ok, even though they could be optimized a bit. What's your problem actually? Do you get a parse error? If so tell us your input and the results you get.